# ItemDataBound 'e.item.dataitem("key")' with ListView Control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview, asp.net-3.5, itemdatabound

With the ASP.NET Repeater control, I am used to being able to access my data item values in the `ItemDataBound` Event Handler by doing:

```
e.item.dataitem("column_name")
```

However, it seems with the ListView control this is not possible. How can I access the data item values?