# In DataList ItemdataBound event, how to access by column name instead of by ItemArray index

Tags: asp.net, datalist, itemdatabound, dataitem

In the following code, `strUsername` is always returning as an empty string "" (and so are other columns).

However, if I use `ItemArray` and access it by passing the column index, it works fine. How to access by column name instead of index?

```
protected void dlst_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        if (e.Item.DataItem != null)
        {
            string strUsername = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "Username").ToString(); -----> this returns as an empty string
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the asp.net markup for this control?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is here: [ItemDataBound 'e.item.dataitem("key")' with ListView Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3195557/itemdatabound-e-item-dataitemkey-with-listview-control)

Also, `DataBinder.Eval` **is not usable** in `ItemDataBound`.